# Bullet: No Bouncing off the walls

Tags: c++, collision-detection, bullet-physics, rigid-body-dynamics

I'm using Bullet Physics for Collision Detection in a first person game. The collision basically work fine, I cannot walk through objects. But if I walk against the wall and release the key I get bounced back and automatically move backwards. This is something I do not want. The player should not be bouncing off when walking into a wall, it just shouldn't be possible to pass through it.

Here are some code snippets.

Creating the Player-RigidBody (class Camera):

```
btCollisionShape* _collisionShape = new btCapsuleShapeZ(0.2f, 1.0f);
btDefaultMotionState* _motionState = new btDefaultMotionState(btTransform(
    btQuaternion(1, 0, 0, 1),
    btVector3(_position.x, _position.y, _position.z)        
    ));
btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo cameraRigidBodyCI(
    10,                 
    _motionState,       
    _collisionShape,    
    btVector3(0, 0, 0)  
    );
_rigidBody = new btRigidBody(cameraRigidBodyCI);
_rigidBody->setActivationState(DISABLE_DEACTIVATION);
```

Creating the RigidBody of the Walls and other box-objects:

```
btVector3 rigidBodyPos;
btCollisionShape* collisionShape;
glm::vec3* minMax = getMinMaxVertexCoords();
glm::vec3 minCoords = minMax[0];
glm::vec3 maxCoords = minMax[1];
glm::vec3 middleSize = glm::vec3((maxCoords.x - minCoords.x) / 2, (maxCoords.y - minCoords.y) / 2, (maxCoords.z - minCoords.z) / 2);
glm::vec3 middlePos = glm::vec3((maxCoords.x + minCoords.x) / 2, (maxCoords.y + minCoords.y) / 2, (maxCoords.z + minCoords.z) / 2);

collisionShape = new btBoxShape(btVector3(middleSize.x, middleSize.y, middleSize.z));
rigidBodyPos = btVector3(middlePos.x, middlePos.y, middlePos.z);

btMotionState* motionState = new btDefaultMotionState(btTransform(
    btQuaternion(0, 0, 0, 1),   
    rigidBodyPos                
    ));
btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo* rigidBodyCI = new btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo(
    0,                  
    motionState,
    collisionShape,
    btVector3(0, 0, 0)  
    );
if (_rigidBody != nullptr){
    delete _rigidBody;
    _rigidBody = nullptr;
}
_rigidBody = new btRigidBody(*rigidBodyCI);
_rigidBody->setActivationState(DISABLE_DEACTIVATION);
_rigidBody->setRestitution(0.0f);
```

The Collision-Detection itself:

```
dynamicsWorld->updateAabbs();
dynamicsWorld->stepSimulation(1 / 60.f, 10);
//...
btTransform cameraTrans = camera->getRigidBody()->getWorldTransform();
camera->setPosition(glm::vec3(cameraTrans.getOrigin().getX(), cameraTrans.getOrigin().getY(), cameraTrans.getOrigin().getZ()));
```

How can I change this behaviour?

Comment: I somehow managed to solve it... But honestly, I have no idea how.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the player object moves into a wall and the position is updated, then collision is detected and the players position is then corrected creating a "bouncing" effect. To correct this, compute your collisions prior to moving the player (or probably any object).